# How to use CFileCache and Memcache togther in Yii

Tags: php, caching, yii

I have to cache view (HTML) using  **CFileCache** and (varaible, object) using **Memcache**.

how to configure it at the same time:

what I need like :

in views

```
<?php if($this->beginCache($id)) { ?>
...content to be cached...
<?php $this->endCache(); } ?>
...other HTML content...
```

so the execution of  previous code it will output **file** like (**xxxxxx.bin**)

and in my acton I have to save in memory (**Memcache**) like:

```
$user = $this->getUserById(2);
Yii::app()->cache->set('user2', $user);
Yii::app()->cache->get('user2');
```

So all variable and objects will saved in Memory

and my main.php:

```
'cache'=>array(
   'class'=>'system.caching.CFileCache',
 ),
```

in addition ,if I have to use **APC** for **opcode** how to configure it with other cache type to use more than one cache type in my application.

Any help abut how to configure that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this, but you can try to define something like

```
'cache'=>array(
   'class'=>'system.caching.CFileCache',
 ),
'memcache'=>array(
   'class'=>'system.caching.CMemCache',
 ),
```

Then you should be able to do

```
Yii::app()->memcache->set('user2', $user);
Yii::app()->memcache->get('user2');
```

I really have not tried this but considering how you define db connections and other things in Yii this should work.